# How do you diagnose the steps of opendkim

Tags: email, postfix, opendkim

So I've been spending a few hours today upgrading the server I work on to sign emails with DKIM using opendkim and postfix.
It actually works! The problem though is when I use a tool, such as the check-auth verifier, the lookup of the public key fails. This is because for some reason, instead of looking up mydomain.com it is trying to look up Â  Â mydomain.com. but I literally have no idea where it is getting the Â  Â  from.

I've checked over the opendkim.conf file and deleted the Domain mydomain.com and rewritten it, then also regenerated the keys, even going so far as to type the command out by hand, just in case there is some sort of funky internet copy paste going on here. The problem, however, continues to plague me! I used https://dkimvalidator.com/ and see the following info:

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=Â  Â mydomain.com;
s=default; t=redacted;

So what I am asking is, where does it draw that -d section from? Clearly that is what is breaking the entire thing, but where is it getting that from?
Thanks